# can I devlop a app with Jcommpament class?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, jpanel

**What are the uses of JFrame class?**
Can I do app with Jcommpament class?

Comment: Read [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 3):

The `JFrame` is the main container of your [Swing Java Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). It holds the main panel, the toolbar, ect. It's usually the first thing you'll instantiate in your application and add other components to.

The `JPanel` is a container for other components. Each subsection of logically related components should be added to a `JPanel` to make drawing and reorganizing of those components easier to manage.